# How to combine labeled graphics?

Tags: plotting

If we have two or more labels graphs, and we want to put them in a bigger graph at specific locations, how can we do it?

I tried the following and it does not work

```
graph1 = Labeled[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}]], "Circle"];
graph2 = Labeled[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}]], "Circle 2"];
Graphics[{graph1, graph2}]
```

---

Update, I need to put the smaller graphs at certain position, not necessarily in a grid.

Comment: Your figures are not "graphs," and thus your original title was misleading.  (I've fixed it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using `Inset` which will let specify arbitrary locations. Like so:

```
circles =
  {Labeled[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}]], "Circle"],
   Labeled[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}]], "Circle 2"]};
locations = {{-1, -1}, {1, 1}};
Graphics[MapThread[Inset[#1, #2] &, {circles, locations}],
  PlotRangePadding -> 1.5,
  Frame -> True]
```

[image: graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `Grid`?

```
Grid[{{graph1, graph2}}]
```

[image]

You can rearrange the location by listing. For example,

```
Grid[{{graph1}, {graph2}}]
```

will put them vertically.
[image]

Comment: I don't really want them to be in a grid.