# Is there any way to turn Labeled[...] into graphics primitives?

Tags: graphics, labeling, conversion

I have asked a similar question [before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190248/52526).

In that question I pointed out that the following code does not work:

```
graph1 = Labeled[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}]], "Circle"];
graph2 = Labeled[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}]], "Circle 2"];
Graphics[{graph1, graph2}]
```

The [accepted solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190261/52526) to my question is to use `Inset`.

But as I pointed out in another [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190301/52526), it's a bit difficult to control the relative sizes of combined graphs.

So here's the question can you turn `Labeled[...]` into graphics primitives so we can easily combine them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[labeledToGraphics]
labeledToGraphics[tr_: {0, 0}] := # /. 
    Labeled[g_, l_] :> Graphics[Translate[{g[[1]], Text[l, {0, -1.2}, Center]}, tr]] &;

Show[labeledToGraphics[] @ graph1, labeledToGraphics[{2.5, 0}] @ graph2]
```

[image]